# Is $f(D)$ a compact set for $D$ compact?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ a function. I know that if $f$ is continuous, then $f(D)$ is compact if $D$ compact. But is it still true if $f$ is not necessarily continuous ? I would say yes. Indeed, let $D$ a compact set and $f(D)\subset Y$. Let $\mathscr U$ a cover of open of $f(D)$. Then
$$f(D)\subset \bigcup_{i\in\mathcal I}U_i.$$
Since 
$$D\subset f^{-1}(f(D))=\bigcup_{i\in\mathcal I}f^{-1}(U_i)$$
and that $D$ is compact, we have $$D\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(U_i).$$
Therefore $$f(D)\subset f\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(U_i)\right)=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\underbrace{f(f^{-1}(U_i))}_{\subset U_i}\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i,$$

and thus, $f(D)$ is compact. Do you think it is right ? The problem is that I know that there is a bijection between $]0,1[$ and $[0,1]$ and thus if $f$ is the bijection, then $f([0,1])=]0,1[$ and thus $f([0,1])$ is not compact. So what's wrong in my proof ?

Answer (score 10):

Your cover of $D$ need not be an open cover, since your map is not continuous.

Comment: nice ;-) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a non-continuous surjection from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$. Setting $D=[0,1]$ then, what do you get?

The problem in your proof is that your $f^{-1}(U_i)$ might not be open if $f$ is not continuous.